# Get the FK attributes of a model , if a model is passed

Tags: django, django-models

I have the following Model(s):

```
class Comp(models.Model):
      ....
       is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Item(models.Model):

      comp = models.ForeignKey(Comp, blank=True, null=True, related_name='items', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        romp = models.ForeignKey(Romp, blank=True, null=True, related_name='items', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

I want to write a generic Model `clean` method,to check for `non Null` Foreign Keys of a Model, if their `is_active=True`

I want to inherit this method over multiple Models(using abstract Model)

In the code below I check each model attribute over a general list of FKs

```
def clean(self, *args, **kwargs):
    ....
            for attr in FK_LIST:
                if hasattr(self, attr):
                    fk_obj = getattr(self, attr)
                    if not fk_obj.active:
                        raise ValidationError({'is_active': 'The {} {} needs to be active first'
                                              .format(type(fk_obj).__name__, fk_obj.name)})
```

There 2 issues with my code:

1. I have two manually maintain a list of FKs name
2. I need to loop thru all attributes instead of checking just FKs
3. Instead of having an implicit FK_list to check in, I prfer to have an exclude list(easy to maintain):
   Check all FK on the model that are not NULL or in Exclude_list

Comment: Only foreign keys? I assume `OneToOneField`s as well? What about other relations like `ManyToManyField`s or `OneToMany`?

Comment: just FK , OnetoOne,  I have like a hierarchical relation, so I just don't want to activate child if parent is not active

Comment: @use3541631: if you define a `OneToOneField`, django automatically makes a reverse field in the referred model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can obtain the list of columns with `self._meta.fields`. This will produce a tuple with the fields, and the value is the column definition.

We can iterate this column, and check if the type is a `ForeignKey`. In  that case we thus perform the check:

```
def clean(self, *args, **kwargs):
    # ...
    for field in self._meta.fields():
        if isinstance(field, ForeignKey):
            fk_obj = getattr(self, field.name)
            if not fk_obj.active:
                raise ValidationError({'is_active': 'The {} {} needs to be active first'
                                              .format(type(fk_obj).__name__, fk_obj.name)})
```

or we can filter out non-inherited ones:

```
def clean(self, *args, **kwargs):
    # ...
    for field in self._meta.get_fields(include_parents=False):
        if isinstance(field, ForeignKey):
            fk_obj = getattr(self, field.name)
            if not fk_obj.active:
                raise ValidationError({'is_active': 'The {} {} needs to be active first'
                                              .format(type(fk_obj).__name__, fk_obj.name)})
```

Comment: how can I get, only FK(attributes) that are declared not inherited(are related): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52127112/get-a-class-instance-only-declared-attributesnot-inherited