# Get a class/instance only declared attributes(not inherited)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-object

I have 3 classes A,B,C , C inherting form A and B:

```
class A:
      a = "ala"

class B:
      b = "bla"

class C(A,B):
      c = "cla"
```

How can I get only the Attributes of C, attributes that are not inherited ?

Comment: well... `vars(C)` works... but where are you looking to get that information? If it's within an instance method, then you can do the same on it's self `_class_`

Comment: I want to loop over them, so in a set/tuple,list

Comment: loop over what though?

Answer (score 2):

You could access the `__dict__` of `C` directly via the `vars` builtin.

```
>>> vars(C)['c']
'cla'
>>> vars(C)['b']
...
KeyError: 'b'
```

There's not much more to say without further context about what your real problem is.